# CURL (PHP 7) NO CONECTA CON UNA URL INDICANDO EL PUERTO

Tags: php, url, curl, puertos

Tenemos una raspberry pi con la cual nos queremos comunicar mediante un fichero php. Para ello usamos cUrl, que viene incluído con php. El problema es que la raspberry está configurada para escuchar el puerto 81 y no conseguimos respuesta a través de curl.
En la raspberry hemos colocado un fichero contesta.php que devuelve una página web básica. La raspberry funciona bien, no es el problema, porque si escribimos en un navegador la **ip:81/contesta.php** todo funciona de forma correcta.
Si lo hacemos a través de curl, no funciona, no devuelve ningún error, simplemente no hace nada. El código que utilizamos es el siguiente:

```php
<?php 
function get_web_page($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_echoTRANSFER,True);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, True);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 6);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 81); // <== Esto es lo que se ha añadido para que llame al puerto 81

    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    echo "Codigo: $httpCode <br>";
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $htmlx    = htmlentities($result);
    echo $htmlx."<br>";
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
}

get_web_page('http://x.xxx.xx.xxx:81/contesta.php');
```

Obtenemos "Codigo: 0" y no devuelve nada más.

Consultado en foros, la única información disponible es que curl necesita la línea 
**curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 81);** para llamar al puerto 81 y simplemente con esto, debería funcionar.

Sin embargo, no es así.

Añadir que el código presentado arriba funciona correctamente cuando queremos llamar a una url que no tiene indicación del puerto, es decir, ip/contesta.php

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: El puerto 81 está abierto en el servidor?

Comment: Sí, el puerto está abierto en el router de la red donde está conectada la raspberry.

Comment: Y en el equipo o servidor donde estás ejecutando el script también está abierto?

Comment: El script lo tenemos alojado en un hosting, en este caso Raiola. No podemos abrir los puertos en un hosting compartido, que yo sepa. Sin embargo, no entiendo para qué quieres abrir el puerto en el hosting desde el que llamas. Habrá que abrirlo en el destino, que es donde está la raspberry escuchando, ¿no? Disculpa si digo alguna barbaridad.

Comment: Se requiere que el puerto esté abierto en el servidor para poder realizar la petición, no hay otra forma.

Comment: ¿Abrir el puerto en Raiola en este caso?¿Es posible hacer eso?

Comment: Eso debes preguntar al administrador del hosting.

Comment: si la ejecucion del curl es desde el mismo equipo no se usa la ip si no localhost o 127.0.0.1 ...

Answer (score 0):

Hemos logrado resolver el problema, pero sin utilizar curl. Se agradece la respuesta de Triby que sugería abrir los puertos en el servidor donde se corría el script php, pero en nuestra solución eso no ha sido necesario.

Simplemente hemos sustituído curl por el siguiente código:

```php
<?php

$respuesta = file_get_contents("http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:81/contesta.php");

print "Respuesta: $respuesta <br>";

?>
```

Nada más. Con esto nos devuelve la página web con formato texto.

Esto nos indica que curl no maneja bien las peticiones url con puertos. Al menos en nuestro caso.

**Edición**

Si bien es cierto que hemos resuelto el problema, la solución funciona para localhost, sin embargo, llevado al servidor de producción, nos arroja un error de Connection refused. Parece ser que por un tema de seguridad del servidor.

Es curioso que, sin el puerto, funciona perfectamente tanto en local como en el servidor. Es decir:

```php
<?php

$respuesta = file_get_contents("http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx/contesta.php");

print "Respuesta: $respuesta <br>";

?>
```

funciona correctamente, también en el servidor.

¿Alguien tiene alguna experiencia al respecto?